# How to use spawn/4?

Tags: elixir, spawn

I'm trying to deploy a function on a remote Elixir node using [`Node.spawn/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Node.html?#spawn/4) but I can't seem to manage it.

I have defined the function in question, (hello world), in a module Hello in iex and tried to deploy it using `Node.spawn(:node2@remote, Hello, :world, [])`.

```
iex(node1@local) defmodule Hello do
...(node1@local) def world, do: IO.puts("Hello World)
...(node1@local) end

Node.spawn(:node2@remote, Hello, :world, [])
```

I would expect spawn/4 to send the module Hello over to the remote node so that the function world/0 is recognized there when trying to spawn it. However, I get the following error:

> [error] Error in process #PID<16431.208.0> on node :node2@remote with exit value: `{:undef, [{Hello, :world, [], []}]}`

Comment: did you try `Node.spawn(:node2@remote, Hello, :world, [[]])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology you use makes it extremely hard to understand what have you tried.

As stated by [`:erlang.spawn/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-4) documentation, this function works in all the aspects exactly as [`:erlang.spawn/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3) except it executed the code on the remote node. There is no *deploy* involved, whatever it means. The remote node must be known to the caller *and* must contain the code to be executed.

There is a great tutorial available at elixir-lang.org — [`Distributed tasks and configuration`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html).

To check if the remote node is visible to the caller, one might call [`Node.connect/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Node.html#connect/1).

Summing up.

Start two named `iex` sessions from two different terminals:

```
$ iex --sname foo
$ iex --sname bar
```

From the first one try:

```
Node.spawn(:bar@localhost, IO, :puts, ["¡YAY!"])
```

You should see `"¡YAY!"` printed. To test your own `Hello.world/0`, this function must be known to the *target node*. So, switch to `:foo@localhost` instance and type:

```
defmodule Hello, do: def world, do: IO.puts("¡YAY!")
```

Now switch to `:bar@localhost` and do:

```
Node.spawn(:foo@localhost, Hello, :world, [])
```

You should see `"¡YAY!"` printed out.